# How can i do copy of my selected sku products to other category in same root category using CSV?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

My root category is **Default Category** under my root category there are 10 nos of sub category, how can i do **copy of my selected sku products to other category** in same root category using CSV.

Note : The selected sku is mingled with various category. I have created category name  **Offer**, i need various categories of products copied to **"Offer" category**

Comment: Done myself  csv header :   sku  |  category_reset  |  categories.
csv values :  123  |   0   |   /Category